# Probability of having more than one multiplication per electron collision?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-electrodynamics

I am studying Gas Electron Multipliers (GEM) where is a common assumption that there is a one primary multiplication per electron collision: Sauli, Nappi and Knoll.
However, I am unsure about this choice. 
This choice leads to linear model about electron avalanche (also called Townsend avalanche/discharge). 
I think more than one multiplication is necessary for nonlinear processes.

Carl says in the comment that *the chance of a second interaction with a single atom (and ejecting two electrons in the process) is vanishingly small*. 
I would like to understand how small.

How can there be more than one multiplication per primary electron collision?
What is the probability of having a second interaction with a single atom?

Comment: I don't think there is, but the existence of an electric field means both the original and the secondary electrons are re-accelerated and cause more electrons to be emitted. Hence the multiplication.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Can you please clarify your comment as an answer more. What are your pieces of evidence that there cannot be more than one multiplication per primary electron collision?

Comment: I suspect a little digging into atomic physics will show that the chance of a second interaction with a single atom (and ejecting two electrons in the process) is vanishingly small.

Comment: Can you give trustworthy probability estimate?

Comment: An electron multiplier would be a completely unsuitable system to test the assumption that more than one multiplication per collision takes place, so it's completely irrelevant what really happens, you are unlikely to discover any deviations from the assumption, to begin with.

Comment: Can you please explain more why? There is still much dynamics which is unknown inside GEM.

Comment: The thing is that the inside of an electron multiplier is a very messy environment, and any tertiary electrons that are generated in any given collision will be buried in the huge number of electrons from later on in the avalanche; to begin with, you don't even count the electrons in the first place. The effect might be there but you need a separate experiment to test it.